# How do I invite someone to my world in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to invite my girlfriend to my world so she could visit my fun-fair, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is she on the same network as you are?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are both connected to the same network (you're both connected to the same Wifi).

In your game, make sure that "Server is visible" is turned on (ticked) in your Game Options menu. Your friend can then use "Join Game" to find and join your world.

Comment: You don't have to be on the same WiFi. You just have to be friends. See my answer.

Comment: We are both on the same WiFi, the host iPad has “Visible to LAN Players” enabled, the other iPad can see the game, which we click on, and we see the message “Unable to connect to world”. WiFi signal is very strong (we are both next to the router).  Any ideas?  This happens a lot to us.

Answer (score 0):

In MCPE, if you are friends on the Xbox (you can get an Xbox app on your device if you don't have an Xbox), your world should show up for her under the 'friends' tab as long as you have multiplayer turned on in the settings, and as long as you are actually playing the world (unless it's a realm or a server... Those work differently). If you are not friends on Xbox, but are on the same internet, it should still show up under the 'friends' tab as long as you have 'visible to LAN' selected under Multiplayer in the world settings. If you are not friends and are not on the same internet, it will not show up until you either become friends or connect to the same internet. Sometimes, once you join a world for the first time, it will still show up every time even if you are no longer friends and are not on the same internet, but I think that's a glitch.