# Is there a way to have my friends join a server in MC PE without having them right next to me?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a server in MC PE for my friend to join but she's at least a mile away can I do this? Will it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I invite someone to my world in Minecraft PE?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147050/how-do-i-invite-someone-to-my-world-in-minecraft-pe)

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/how-to-join-games-with-minecraft-pocket-edition-0-7

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199115/is-it-possible-to-connect-with-other-people-on-minecraft-pocket-edition-without

Answer (score 1):

I've used an app called [Multiplayer for Minecraft PE](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8) for a while.
It's pretty easy to use, as if you and your friend both have the app, you can host a world through the app, and she can find it and join.

The app costs $3, but if you plan to frequently play MCPE with her, it's probably worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you to do this is by downloading software on your computer.[Pocketmine](http://www.pocketmine.net/) is a good example.[This **documentation**](http://pocketmine-mp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) should help you if you have any problems.You then need to know how to port forward your computer.This [website](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) should help you.Make sure the port is 19132.(you'll know what i mean when you get there.

If you don't know what your router name is you need to find your router and look at the back.There should be a sticker that tells you the model.If you google that you should learn what company makes your router and model.

Then you need to give the ip that you got from port forwarding and give it to your friend.She needs to click on edit when she opens up minecraft then click external.She might not to be able to connect all the time because this is a third party software.