# Is it possible to connect with other people on Minecraft Pocket Edition without wifi?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just downloaded minecraft pocket edition. My friend wants to connect with me in her world. Problem is I have no wifi and she lives in a different state.

Comment: Unless you want to pay huge (and I mean massive) data rates to connect, you've already ruled out the standard ways to connect in your question.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198928/is-there-a-way-to-have-my-friends-join-a-server-in-mc-pe-without-having-them-rig

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer... Is no. Unless your willing to use Cellular. Lots of it.

Minecraft PE is a game that *currently* does not **officially** support Bluetooth functionality so Wi-Fi or Cellular is the only way. There are some "fixes" people do online allowing you to play over Bluetooth, but you said your friend lives nowhere near you so that won't work.

## Playing Minecraft PE Worldwide

Clicking [**this link**](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Online-Worldwide-Minecraft-PE-Multiplayer) will show you a guide to playing online in Minecraft PE.

(After reading the above), If you go through with downloading 3rd Party apps, there are lots to choose from.

A popular choice (for iOS), also been the very first of it's kind, is **Multiplayer for Minecraft PE**. which can be found [**here**](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8) on the App Store. (Instructions included in the WikiHow link, also [**here**](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Online-Worldwide-Minecraft-PE-Multiplayer) if you missed it)